# How to change variable stored in parent class from an inherited class in C++

Tags: c++

So as the title suggests I am attempting to change the `number` variable, originally stored as 1000. Change this variable in another class function, and then replace the original value (1000) with the newly updated `number`. I haven't been able to find anything online to help me with this.

I have tried using pointers to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class data {
protected:
    int number = 1000;
};

class fetchData : public data {
public:
    int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    int updateNumber(int newNumber) {
        number = newNumber;
        return number;
    }
};

class function : public fetchData {
public:
    void minusNumber(int numberTakeAway) {
        int newNumber = number - numberTakeAway;
        updateNumber(newNumber);
        cout << "Taken away: " << numberTakeAway << endl;
        cout << "\nShould be new number: " << number << endl; // Not updating parent class variable
    }
};

void printData() {
    fetchData r;
    cout << "number: " << r.getNumber() << endl;
}

void minusNumber() {
    function r;
    r.minusNumber(200);
}

int main(void) {
    fetchData q;
    cout << "\nOriginal ";
    printData();
    cout << "\n";
    minusNumber();
    cout << "\nActual ";
    printData();
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no connection between instances of fetchData in your functions. What else do you expect to happen?

Comment: Please show what output you get and what you expect. The problem is likely not with how you set the `number` member, but with the free functions operating on function-local variables that are not related to one another.

Comment: To add on, your functions should take a `fetchdata` as a parameter, not declare a brand new one in the function. I currently see no reason for the `function` class to be its own thing. It should just be a part of `fetchdata`.

Comment: @sweenish Or `function`. And take them by-reference.

Comment: @walnut Yeah; I have a hard time finding the right mix of detail and terseness in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done in the free functions is to create a new *instance* of your class. If you want to do something with `q` that you instantiated in main, you have to pass it. Or use the member function in your class. So below, I've changed `printData` to take a reference to `q`. And instead of calling the free function `minusNumber`, I've called the member function of your class. I deleted the free function as it is not used.

```
#include <iostream>
class data {
protected:
    int number = 1000;
};

class fetchData : public data {
public:
    int getNumber() const {
        return number;
    }

    int updateNumber(int newNumber) {
        number = newNumber;
        return number;
    }
};

class function : public fetchData {
public:
    void minusNumber(int numberTakeAway) {
        int newNumber = number - numberTakeAway;
        updateNumber(newNumber);
        std::cout << "Taken away: " << numberTakeAway << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\nShould be new number: " << number << std::endl; // Not updating parent class variable
    }
};

void printData(const function& r) {
    std::cout << "number: " << r.getNumber() << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
    function q;
    std::cout << "\nOriginal ";
    printData(q);
    std::cout << "\n";
    q.minusNumber(200);
    std::cout << "\nActual ";
    printData(q);
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok this seemed to work. However, how come that when I add a simple for statement to the main function. In theory it should remove 200 from the number each iteration no? It seems to just output that the new number is 800. Thus not actually updating the actual parent variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have. I added another `minusNumber(200);` in main and then the next print is _600_. [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07e11abb74668dc8) And I peeked at the data i `q`, it is 600.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing between static - class members, and non static - instance members.

`number` is an instance member which means every instance will have its own `number` with its own value.

Each of your functions `main`, `printData`, and `minusNumber` creates its own instance of `function` or `fetchData` class, and there is no connection between them.

Try this code, where there is only one instance:

```
int main(void) {
    function q;
    cout << "\nOriginal ";
    q.printData();
    cout << "\n";
    q.minusNumber(200);
    cout << "\nActual ";
    q.printData();
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: his classes don't have a member `printData`. That just needs a const reference to the object to be called.